Extra \else and File '.def' not found. ^^M errors in ej-c.sty file
I am trying to compile this Tex file with this style file in the same directory, following these instructions. I am using TeXstudio 4.8.1.
I am getting the following error messages:
e-jc.sty error 73 Extra \else
e-jc.sty error 73 File '.def' not found. ^^M

What are these and how can I solve them?
Update
A teX file as simple as this one causes the issue:
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[amsmath]{e-jc}

\begin{document}
    The reconstruction  
\end{document}

The content of the style file is:
%% Style file for the Electronic Journal of Combinatorics
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{e-jc}[2023/07/03 Electronic Journal of Combinatorics]

% We change the footnote style to alphabetic in this style file
% for use in the author list.  Then it is changed back to numeric
% by \maketitle

\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\textit{\alph{footnote}}}
\renewcommand{\thanks}[1]{\textbf{Please don't use ``thanks''.}}

\def\get@fnmark#1{%
    \begingroup
    \c@footnote #1\relax
    \unrestored@protected@xdef\@thisfnmark{\thefootnote}%
    \endgroup
    \@thisfnmark}
\def\authornote#1{\unskip\kern0.03em\proc@anote#1,,,,\endproc@anote}
\def\proc@anote#1,#2,#3,#4,#5\endproc@anote
{\def\@anoteA{\get@fnmark{#1}}%
    \ifx\relax#2\relax\let\@anoteB=\relax\else\def\@anoteB{,\get@fnmark{#2}}\fi
    \ifx\relax#3\relax\let\@anoteC=\relax\else\def\@anoteC{,\get@fnmark{#3}}\fi
    \ifx\relax#4\relax\let\@anoteD=\relax\else\def\@anoteD{,\get@fnmark{#4}}\fi
    \rlap{\@textsuperscript{\normalfont\@anoteA\@anoteB\@anoteC\@anoteD}}}
% \authortext accepts for its first argument either a number or {} or { }.
% The last two cases and number 0 create a footnote with an empty label.
\long\def\the@authortext{}
\long\def\authortext#1#2{%
    \ifx\relax#1\relax
    \g@addto@macro\the@authortext{\footnotetext[0]{\raggedright #2}}\else
    \ifx#1 % intentional space before percent
    \g@addto@macro\the@authortext{\footnotetext[0]{\raggedright #2}}\else
    \g@addto@macro\the@authortext{\footnotetext[#1]{\raggedright #2}}\fi\fi}

\newcommand\email[1]{\texttt{#1}}

% Use hanging indentation in footnotes
\long\def\@makefntext#1{\parindent 1.02em\noindent
    \everypar={\hangindent=1.02em}\hangindent=1.02em
    \hb@xt@1em{\hss\@textsuperscript{\normalfont\@thefnmark}}\kern0.02em #1}

\renewcommand\maketitle{\par
    \begingroup
    \def\@makefnmark{\rlap{\@textsuperscript{\normalfont\@thefnmark}}}%
    \newpage
    \global\@topnum\z@   % Prevents figures from going at top of page.
    \the@authortext
    \@maketitle
    \thispagestyle{plain} % \@thanks
    \endgroup
    \setcounter{footnote}{0}%
    \renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\arabic{footnote}}
    \global\let\maketitle\relax
    \global\let\@maketitle\relax
    \global\let\@author\@empty
    \global\let\@date\@empty
    \global\let\@title\@empty
    \global\let\title\relax
    \global\let\author\relax
    \global\let\date\relax
    \global\let\and\relax}

\DeclareOption{amsmath}{\let\use@amsmath=\relax}
\DeclareOption{cleveref}{\let\use@cleveref=\relax}
\ProcessOptions\relax

\RequirePackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\ifx\use@amsmath\undefined\else\RequirePackage{amsmath}\fi
\RequirePackage{amsthm,amssymb}
\RequirePackage[colorlinks=true,citecolor=black,linkcolor=black,urlcolor=blue]{hyperref}

\setlength{\textwidth}{160mm}
\setlength{\textheight}{221mm}
\setlength{\topmargin}{0pt}
\setlength{\headsep}{0pt}
\setlength{\headheight}{0pt}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0pt}
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{0pt}
\setlength{\footskip}{9mm}

\renewcommand{\geq}{\geqslant}
\renewcommand{\leq}{\leqslant}
\renewcommand{\ge}{\geqslant}
\renewcommand{\le}{\leqslant}

\newenvironment{corrigendum}[1]%
{\clearpage\newpage\section*{Corrigendum -- submitted #1}}{}

\newcommand{\reusenumber}[2]{\setcounter{#1}{#2}\addtocounter{#1}{-1}}

\newcommand{\specs}[4]{\def\papno{#1}\def\volno{#2}\def\volyear{#3}\def\papid{#4}}
\ifx\volno\undefined\def\volno{30}\fi
\ifx\volyear\undefined\def\volyear{2023}\fi
\ifx\papno\undefined\def\papno{P00}\fi
\ifx\papid\undefined\def\papid{00000}\fi

\newcommand{\Copyright}[1]{\def\copy@right{\copyright\thinspace\ignorespaces#1}}
\newcommand{\dateline}[3]{\def\the@dateline{Submitted: \ignorespaces#1;
        Accepted: \ignorespaces#2; Published: \ignorespaces#3\\[0.5ex]\copy@right}}
\newcommand{\MSC}[1]{\def\the@MSC{\ignorespaces#1}}

\let\old@maketitle\maketitle
\renewcommand{\maketitle}{\date{\small\the@dateline}\old@maketitle}

\renewenvironment{abstract}{%
    \small
    \begin{center}%
        {\bfseries \abstractname\vspace{-.5em}\vspace{\z@}}%
    \end{center}%
    \quotation}%
{\par\smallskip\noindent
    \textbf{Mathematics Subject Classifications: }\the@MSC\endquotation} 

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%% The next group of commands makes the font smaller for the title and
%% for section and subsection headings, and adjusts the space just below 
%% each such heading.

\renewcommand\title[1]{\gdef\@title{\reset@font\Large\bfseries #1}}
\renewcommand\section{\@startsection {section}{1}{\z@}%
    {-3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
    {2.3ex \@plus.2ex}%
    {\normalfont\large\bfseries}}
\renewcommand\subsection{\@startsection{subsection}{2}{\z@}%
    {-3ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
    {1.5ex \@plus .2ex}%
    {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}
\renewcommand\subsubsection{\@startsection{subsubsection}{3}{\z@}%
    {-2.5ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
    {1.5ex \@plus .2ex}%
    {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}

\renewcommand\paragraph{\@startsection{paragraph}{4}{\z@}%
    {2ex \@plus.5ex \@minus.2ex}%
    {-1em}%
    {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}

\renewcommand\subparagraph{\@startsection{subparagraph}{5}{\parindent}%
    {2ex \@plus.5ex \@minus .2ex}%
    {-1em}%
    {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}

% These font declarations are for the footer appearing on all pages.
\newfont{\footsc}{cmcsc10 at 8truept}
\newfont{\footbf}{cmbx10 at 8truept}
\newfont{\footrm}{cmr10 at 10truept}
\newfont{\foottt}{cmtt10 at 10truept}

\renewcommand{\ps@plain}{%
    \renewcommand{\@oddfoot}{\footsc the electronic journal of combinatorics
        {\footbf\volno} (\volyear), \#\papno\hfil
        \ifnum\value{page}>1{\thepage}\else
        \href{https://doi.org/10.37236/\papid}{\foottt
            https://doi.org/10.37236/\papid\kern0.1em}\fi}}

\pagestyle{plain}
\g@addto@macro\bfseries{\boldmath}

%%%  Squashing the bibliography together a bit
\newlength{\BiblioSpacing}
\setlength{\BiblioSpacing}{0.4ex plus 0.1ex minus 0.1ex}
\newcommand{\SquashBibFurther}{%
    \setlength{\BiblioSpacing}{0.2ex plus 0.1ex}}

\let\oldthebibliography\thebibliography
\let\endoldthebibliography\endthebibliography
\renewenvironment{thebibliography}[1]{%
    \begin{oldthebibliography}{#1}%
        \setlength{\parskip}{\BiblioSpacing}
        \setlength{\itemsep}{\BiblioSpacing}
        \ifdefined\bibsep\setlength{\bibsep}{\BiblioSpacing}\fi% for natbib
    }%
    {%
    \end{oldthebibliography}%
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\ifx\use@cleveref\undefined
\else
\ifx\cleverefoptions\undefined
\RequirePackage{cleveref}%
\else
\RequirePackage[\cleverefoptions]{cleveref}%
\fi
\fi

\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{corollary}[theorem]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{fact}[theorem]{Fact}
\newtheorem{observation}[theorem]{Observation}
\newtheorem{claim}[theorem]{Claim}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Definition}
\newtheorem{example}[theorem]{Example}
\newtheorem{conjecture}[theorem]{Conjecture}
\newtheorem{open}[theorem]{Open Problem}
\newtheorem{problem}[theorem]{Problem}
\newtheorem{question}[theorem]{Question}

\theoremstyle{remark}
\newtheorem{remark}[theorem]{Remark}
\newtheorem{note}[theorem]{Note}

% For linking to an arXiv article:
\newcommand{\arxiv}[1]{\href{https://arxiv.org/abs/#1}{\texttt{arXiv:#1}}}

% Typeset a doi. Some magic to make underscores work:
\def\doi{\begingroup\catcode`\_=12\relax\doi@arg}
\def\doi@arg#1{\href{https://doi.org/#1}{\texttt{doi:#1}}\endgroup}


questions shouldn't rely on external links, which change over time. please post a minimal example which demonstrates the problem in your question.

I get no error. How are you running LaTeX on the file?

I have set the ejc-sample.tex as the root document in TeXstudio, then I click on the double green arrows (Build & View F5)

could you also add the .log to your question? if people are having trouble reproducing the error, the log can help us figure out why.

I don't get an error with any of latex, pdflatex, xelatex or lualatex.

https://texlive.net/run?%5Cdocumentclass%7Bbook%7D%0A%5Cusepackage%7Bamsthm%7D%0A%5Cusepackage%7Bhyperref%7D%0A%5Cusepackage%7Bcleveref%7D%0A%5Cnewtheorem%7Bplemma%7D%5Bchapter%5D%7BLemma%7D%0A%5Cbegin%7Bdocument%7D%0A%5Cchapter%7BS%7D%0A%5Cbegin%7Bplemma%7D%0A%20%20T%0A%5Cend%7Bplemma%7D%0A%5Cend%7Bdocument%7D

I suspect some file encoding problem. No error for me.

please show you log up to the point of the error,

I’m voting to close this question because the issue cannot be reproduced

I fixed this issue by reinstalling MikTeX and TexStudio from scratch, although my installation was working fine with all my .tex files before.
Warning: After re-installing TexStudio, I noticed in the settings that it was pointing to the old installation of MikTeX, as if it picked something left in the registry. I manually updated the settings to point to the correct MikTex directory.
